# Escaping double quotes with back slash

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
const ratingSettings = {performer: true, chiefEngineer: true, engineer: true, customer: true}
```

And I want to convert it to GraphQL string similar like to have all double quotes escaped with back slash:

```
"{\"performer\":true,\"chiefEngineer\":true,\"engineer\":true,\"customer\":true}"
```

I tried the following:

```
const ratingSettings = JSON.stringify({performer: true, chiefEngineer: true, engineer: true, customer: true})

const getMutationObject = data => Object.keys(data).map(key => `${key}: "${data[key]}"`).join(' ')

const userData = getMutationObject(ratingSettings);
```

but I get not quite what I need:

```
"{"performer":true,"chiefEngineer":true,"engineer":true,"customer":true}"
```

I need all double quotes to be escaped with \

Thanks in advance for provided solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` the object, then use `.replace` to replace all `"`s with `\\"`:

```js
const ratingSettings = {performer: true, chiefEngineer: true, engineer: true, customer: true}
const escapedJSON = JSON.stringify(ratingSettings)
  .replace(/"/g, '\\"');
console.log(escapedJSON);
```

Answer (score 2):

> but I get not quite what I need:
>
> ```
> "{"performer":true,"chiefEngineer":true,"engineer":true,"customer":true}"
> ```

That **isn't** what you have. It's a representation in a GUI that shows you have a string (hence the `"` around the outside) containing `{"performer":true,"chiefEngineer":true,"engineer":true,"customer":true}`. The outside quotes are not part of the value at all.

To wrap the string you already have with `"` while escaping all the `"` inside it: Use `JSON.stringify` **again**:

```
const ratingSettings = JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify({performer: true, chiefEngineer: true, engineer: true, customer: true}))
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const string = JSON.stringify(object);
const escaped = string.replace(/"/g, '\"');
```

Comment: Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code or expound on why this is the solution to the question.

Answer (score -1):

JSON.stringify should produce the required result for you.

```js
    const expectedResult = "{\"performer\":true,\"chiefEngineer\":true,\"engineer\":true,\"customer\":true}";
    const result = JSON.stringify({performer: true, chiefEngineer: true, engineer: true, customer: true});
    
    if(result === expectedResult) {
     console.log('You are doing it right!!!');
    }
```

When you log the result of escaped string you can't see the escaped chars in console that's what your confusion.