# convert string to a string Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Sorry , please bare with me , ah I would just like to ask for the terminology and how do we implement or convert a string into something like below. I am not sure if that is string array or something but the output should look like the example.

Thanks for any help and ideas. Appreciated.

```
let a = 'propertyAccountId';

output = "[\"propertyAccountId\"]"

let b = 'name';
output = "[\"name\"]"
```

Comment: Your output is also a string, not an array of strings. It is probably the JSON representation of a string array but that is a different thing.

Comment: Oh I see , how do we achieve that format using javascript Sir ? if you dont mind

Comment: Indeed, JSON of an array containing the string. `JSON.stringify([b])` should do it.

Comment: Create an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays) that contains only the input string then produce its JSON representation using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert array to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping double quotes with back slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59678213/escaping-double-quotes-with-back-slash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For get the output you desire you could do this:

```
const b = 'name'
const output = JSON.stringify([b])
```

Comment: Why `.split()`?

Comment: Thats a weird way to convert to an array... why not `[ b ]` ?

Comment: how will this include the / ?

Comment: the \ inside the array

Comment: I needed Sir the example format "[\"name\"]" include the /

Comment: Those double quotes are only escaped because you're using double quotes to enclose the string in your example.

Comment: Thank you for the details and explnation Sir , thanks.

Comment: The purpose of [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is not to wrap the input into an array. Incidentally it has this effect when invoked without arguments but this is bad practice. Use `[b]` (or `new Array()` followed by `.push()`) to create an array having only one element.

Comment: @axiac aww ok, I didn't know that it a bad practice, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score -1):

```
let a = "propertyAccountId";

function convert(stringvar){
   var newstring = `["${stringvar}"]`
   return newstring;
}

console.log(convert(a));
```

See desired output in console here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-leaf-ioxb26?file=/src/index.js:0-143

Hope this helped.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score -1):

I get roleIds from backend, if a user has only 1 role the roleIds become string and not array so we have to convert it to array by **[ ]** in angular TokenService class:

```
get roleIds(): string[] {

    let roles: string[] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.decodedToken['RoleIds']));

    let roleIds: string[] = [];
    if (typeof roles == "string") { // if user has "only 1 role" the roles is a string
      roleIds = [roles]; // convert to array
    } else { // // if user has "more than 1 role" roles is string[] array (array typeof is object)
      roleIds = roles;
    }

    return roleIds;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can turn your string input to your requested string output like below:

```js
let a = 'propertyAccountId';
let b = 'name';
const convert = input => {
  return JSON.stringify([input])
}

console.log(convert(a))
console.log(convert(b))
```

#### Edit

Removed unnecessary replace function

Comment: This converts into the required string format with escaped double quote

Comment: Don't confuse the value of a variable as data (`["name"]`) with its representation as JSON or as JavaScript code. There is no backslash in the data, it exists only in the source code and in the JSON representation because in these representations the quote character (`"`) has a special meaning and it needs to be escaped to represent itself.